# Visual Studio 2015 won't display local web page (ms-appx ?)

Tags: visual-studio, webview

I'm converting an app to run as a Universal Windows App using VS 2015 Community. If I create a webview using the toolbox, I can enter "http://www.google.com" into the Source property, and it will display google.

If I use the drop down on the Source property to reference (say) Help.htm as a local resource, the source windows displays "ms-appx:///Help.htm". Similarly if it is in Assets, it displays "ms-appx:///Assets/Help.htm". When I run the program, where the webview should appear it displays "You will need a new app to display this ms-appx" and invites me to search the store.

I can display a local image in an image box with very similar syntax, with Source being "ms-appx:///Assets/StoreLogo.png". The Source property in this case is in the "common" group, not "miscellaneous", but apart from that appears virtually identical.

Nor can I specify a local path in a URI (although again I can display Google). Behaviour is identical on two different machines. I have spent several days trying to work out what is going on; any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try to load file through code and share results?

```
public MainPage()   
{  
    this.InitializeComponent();  
    mywebview.Source = newUri("ms-appx-web:///Help.htm");  

}
```

also try this

```
mywebview.Navigate(newUri("ms-appx-web:///Help.htm"));
```

If both above options doesn't work. Please change to below and share results

```
mywebview.NavigateToString("<Html><Body><h1>Eureka!!!!<h1><Body></Html>");
```

Comment: Yes, changing "ms-appx:" to "ms-appx-web:" fixes the problem. Strange indeed that if you go properties of the webView and select an existing file it will insert "ms-appx:Help.html" instead of the correct "ms-appx-web:Help.html" as the reference. But now that I know, no problem. Thank you very much for your assistance.

Comment: i'm also surprised why ms-appx:///Help.html is not working. I have open ticket with Microsoft. Will update once hear from them

Comment: @PeterWebb - Here is reply to query

Comment: Thank you for contacting us regarding the WebView issue.

You are correct in saying that the WebView control needs to use the "ms-appx-web" prefix for local source files. This has also been documented in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/web-view.

Support for these types of URI prefixes in the XAML designer of Visual Studio is very limited at this point. We may consider adding better support for these in the future but at this point you will need to add the appropriate prefix manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it from a Library project, you must also add the name of the library, like that:

```
ms-appx-web:///[Library]/Help.htm
```